# Liquibase database changelog for snowflake

Tags: liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looking for opinions here , I know snowflake is not under supported db's list by Liquibase , but as per doc's Liquibase can be used for unsupported databases as well (may requires some customization). Would be great to know anyone already experienced in using LB versioning for Snowflake and Any challenges faced?

Answer (score 0):

There is a community [liquibase-snowflake plugin](https://github.com/CDKGlobal/liquibase-snowflake), but I know very little about it other than that it exists.

Comment: Thanks steve , i will check it out.